# Is it possible to persistently display the react-dates calendar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dates

I'm trying to have Airbnb's react-dates library display the calendar persistently (i.e. not have it act like a drawer/modal that toggles it's visibility).

I've looked through the documentation and noticed the `appendToBody` prop, but that just puts the `DayPickerRangeController` behind the input fields. It gets somewhat close, in that the calendar is somewhat CSS blocked, but it's still a drawer/modal that disappears.

I've looked through the CSS and can get the calendar to display `inline-block` basically when an input field is focused by removing the `position: absolute` CSS value on the `DateRangePicker_picker` div element. However, it still disappears when the input focus is lost.

The other approach I tried was to use the internal components that `DateRangePicker` is using (e.g. `DateRangePickerInputController` and `DayPickerRangeController`). I am able to have more control from a visual layout standpoint, but I lose all built-in functionality that the `DateRangePicker` has in terms of selecting days/dates/ranges and sending that info back.

```js
<DateRangePickerInputController
  readOnly 
  endDate={endDate} 
  endDateId="endDate" 
  endDatePlaceholderText="mm/dd/yyyy" 
  isEndDateFocused={focusedInput === 'endDate'}
  isStartDateFocused={focusedInput === 'startDate'}
  startDate={startDate} 
  startDateId="startDate" 
  startDatePlaceholderText="mm/dd/yyyy" 
/>
<DayPickerRangeController
  noBorder
  endDate={endDate} 
  focusedInput={focusedInput} 
  initialVisibleMonth={() => !startDate ? moment().subtract(1, 'M') : startDate }
  isOutsideRange={isOutsideRange.bind(this)} 
  minimumNights={0} 
  numberOfMonths={numberOfMonths}
  onDatesChange={onDatesChange.bind(this)} 
  onFocusChange={onFocusChange.bind(this)} 
  orientation={orientation}
  startDate={startDate} 
/>
```

As I mentioned, the elements render the way I want them to in that the calendar and inputs are persistent and stacked "on top" of each other.

And only 1 month shows up correctly, but when I click on a day in the calendar, the `startDate` input field does not update. Same for `endDate`. The hover highlighting over the days in the calendar is gone. And individual day highlights/coloring is gone when I click on them.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `props renderCalendarInfo` and transfer the `DateRangePickerInputController` through it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although this answer might be helpful for the asking person, please elaborate a bit more next time. For more guidance, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer